# Does "Sketchy Information" draw the highest available cost card?

Tags: hearthstone

**Sketchy Information** reads

> Draw a Deathrattle card that costs (4) or less. Trigger its
> Deathrattle.

Will a 4 cost card always be chosen if one is available in my deck? Or is it a random choice between all valid (4-or-less) cost cards?

If I have multiple 4-cost cards, is the choice random or is there any way to predict what is chosen?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any card that matches the conditions of Deathrattle AND 4 mana or less, it does not say "draw the highest cost" one like [Taelan Fordring](https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Taelan_Fordring) does.

[image]

For example, if you had
[Ticket Master](https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Ticket_Master), [Loot Hoarder](https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Loot_Hoarder_(Core)), and Taelan in your deck it would randomly choose between Ticket Master and Loot Hoarder. If you had drawn the Loot Hoarder already, you would be guaranteed to draw the Ticket Master.